# Increased CPU usage with a larger window?

Tags: java

So I just started a game and began working with full screen for the first time. When I run the program though, my CPU usage floats between 20%-30%. When I change the screen size to 100x100px instead, it reduces the usage to around 5%-8%. Does changing the size of the window affect CPU usage? If so, is there a way to reduce it? Here is a sample of my code:

Core class (Extends JPANEL/RUNNABLE)

```
public Core()
 {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());      
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setPreferredSize(screenSize);

    //REMOVE THIS WHEN DONE-----------------------//
    getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false), "leave");
    getActionMap().put("leave", new AbstractAction() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    //-----------------------------------------//

    t = new Thread(this);
    running = true;
    t.start();

    new Display(TITLE, screenSize, this);
}
@Override
public void run() 
{
    while(running)
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(9);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {   
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //ADD UPDATE
        //ADD REPAINT();
    }
}
```

Display class (extends JPanel):

```
public Display(String TITLE, Dimension screenSize, Core c)
{
    setTitle(TITLE);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setResizable(false);
    add(c);
    pack();
    setLocation(screenSize.width/2 - getSize().width/2, screenSize.height/2 - getSize().height/2); //Centers the window

    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: If you are processing a lot of different pixels and graphics, then yes, more pixels will naturally use more CPU. If you want to know how to reduce the CPU usage, then post a new question with a specific bit of code that is using the CPU (Your current code doesn't show anything that we can help with). Side note: use a timer instead of `Thread.sleep`, it works much better.

Comment: Instead `setLocation(...)` use `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` for the same effect, but which takes into consideration things like the taskbar and dock

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did that originally, but the window was offset by a few pixels, making it not really in the center. That was the fix i found.

Comment: @Chrate If it's offset, then you're doing something wrong